# Terraform Google Cloud Run Module does not work with variables

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-run

We want to setup Keycloak using Google Cloud Run via Terraform and the Google Cloud Run Module.
However, we always get an error when we provide a Terraform variable in the `env_secret_vars` section. Providing a string directly runs without error. We also tried various other variants, for example, by enforcing the needed types with the corresponding functions (cf. [here](https://github.com/edu-hub-project/edu-hub-infrastructure/blob/34056e82cfe2e5581be2e6f43373567ace6e7b62/tf/keycloak.tf#L127)). But nothing works - only providing directly a string (cf. [here](https://github.com/edu-hub-project/edu-hub-infrastructure/blob/34056e82cfe2e5581be2e6f43373567ace6e7b62/tf/keycloak.tf#L138)).
Does anyone have suggestions, or is it a bug in the module?

Terrform module: GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-run/google; version 0.2.0
Terraform version: 1.1.6

Error message:

```
Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
```

on .terraform/modules/cloud_run/main.tf line 59, in resource "google_cloud_run_service" "main":

```
          for_each = env.value.value_from
```

Cannot use a set of object value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.